# Gas hob clicking

Tags: gas, gas-burner

I have a 5 ring whirlpool gas hob and out of the blue it started clicking (sparking) on all 5 rings. The only way to stop it is to turn off power. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: More info needed. "*Out of the blue*" ? So you are sitting watching tv and your stove just starts clicking?  "*sparking on all 5 rings*" ? **Please edit your question to describe your problem in detail**. Some proper punctuation would be nice.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of your problem? If it was different than our answers please create your own answer and accept it so if someone else has this problem they can find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the igniter circuit is in parallel any knob turned on fires the circuit.
 If only one ring sparked in the past the control module may have failed.
 One of the switches to start the igniter may be stuck with grease and oil or a wire may have shorted causing the problem. Removing the knob and looking for a lever or switch contact may show what the problem is. If All the levers work a broken switch or failed control unit may be the cause but many times the problem can be found with a visual inspection.

Comment: I have seen stoves where all the igniters click when turning on one burner.  This could be as simple as a frayed or crimped wire that controls the igniter.

Comment: Yes I mentioned that 1 stuck switch or shorted wire could be the cause.